# How to scrape all products short description for the below link?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

```
import requests

page = requests.get("https://www.proflowers.com/mothers-day-flowers-mdf?navContent=T%3aMother%27s+Day%3aBest+Sellers&navLocation=T%3a1-10%3a1-19")


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

for desc in soup.find_all('div', class_="product-summary__short-description"):
    print(desc.p.get_text())
```

### Result:

Sometimes farmers just know best!
Radical roses from Cali! 
The floral equivalent of a heart-eye emoji.
The new Mom's Day motto.
Brave enough to make a big statement.
For your role model, your hero.
Colorful roses!
For a steadfast and strong love.
20% of the purchase price donated to No Kid Hungry.
Prime pastels.
Heavenly blooms from our Premium Rose Collection. 
Go the extra mile with farm fresh roses! 
Lights, camera, satisfaction. 
When we said all the colors, we meant ALL the colors. 
Beautiful & bad day-proof. 
A Ferris wheel of color.
Sometimes beauty whispers. Soft, lavender roses. 
This Bouq is intoxicating.

#### I want to scrape all the products "short description".. can someone pls help me out..Thank you:-)

Comment: Please do proper indentation

Comment: Thank you for the response.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Even after proper indentation, it's giving me only 18 products data because the page is loading only 18 products  at a time I need to scroll the page to load all the products. So can you pls provide me the solution to load all the data before parsing the page.

Comment: Yes, use Selenium, scrolling can't be done with requests. You'll have to use a fake-browser essentially

Comment: okay, Thank you so much :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all the descriptions like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0',
}

page = requests.get(r"https://www.proflowers.com/mothers-day-flowers-mdf?navContent=T%3aMother%27s+Day%3aBest+Sellers&navLocation=T%3a1-10%3a1-19", headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

for desc in soup.find_all('div', class_="name"):
    print(desc.a.get_text().strip())
```

**Output**:

```
One Dozen Rainbow Mother's Day Roses
Two Dozen Rainbow Mother's Day Roses
15 Multi-Colored Tulips for Mom
30 Multi-Colored Tulips for Mom with Brilliant Cut Glass Vase and Chocolates
12 Long Stemmed Rainbow Mother's Day Roses
...
```